# Makefile run processes in background

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I have this in my Makefile:

```
run:
     for x in *.bin ; do ./$$x ; done
```

such that it launches all executables one by one. I want to do this:

```
run:
     for x in *.bin ; do ./$$x &; done
```

so that it starts each executable and puts it in the background. I get a syntax error for the above statement when I put the ampersand.

I dont want to invoke the make as `make &` since this will run processes in the background but still one by one, whereas I want individual executables to run in the background, so that at any instant I have more than one executable running.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to execute via a subshell:

```
run:
     for x in *.bin ; do (./$$x &); done
```

Maybe `make -j` is a better option. Try a `Makefile` that looks something like this:

```
BINS = $(shell echo *.bin)

.PHONY: $(BINS)
run: $(BINS)

*.bin:
    ./$@
```

And then execute with `make -j <jobs>` where `<jobs>` is number of simultaneous jobs to run.

Comment: That's correct. You have to use multiple targets somehow. I updated my answer with a suggested Makefile that should work with -j.

Answer (score 7):

The syntax error you're getting is a shell syntax error, rather than a problem with make syntax.  The ampersand is in fact a [command terminator/separator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03), just as semicolon is; so the way to express the for loop you want is:

```
run:
        for x in *.bin ; do ./$$x & done
```

However, as others have noted, where it's practical it's usually more flexible to express things directly as make dependencies rather than complicated shell snippets and shell loops.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
run:
    for x in *.bin ; do (./$$x &) ; done
```

The ()'s run the command in a subshell.