# Makefile: run binaries differently depending on their name

Tags: makefile

I have this in my Makefile:

```
BINS = $(shell echo *.bin)

.PHONY: $(BINS)
run: $(BINS)

*.bin:
    ./$@
```

I run it as `make -j 8`

This way it looks for all files ending with .bin, and runs them in parallel using make's -j option ([Makefile run processes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668311/makefile-run-processes-in-background/7674033#7674033))

I need to modify the makefile so that it runs all files of the type mpi*.bin as `mpirun -np 2 ./mpi*.bin`, and the remaining executable files as `./<filename>.bin`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example I used to test my answer:

```
touch {a,b,c,d}.bin mpi{a,b,c,d}.bin
```

to create some empty test files, and my Makefile based on yours:

```
BINS = $(shell echo *.bin)

.PHONY: $(BINS)
run: $(BINS)

*.bin:
    echo "bin file: " ./$@

mpi*.bin:
    echo "mpi file: " ./$@
```

It is key here that the rule for the prefixed files *follows* the non-prefixed rule.  If not, the prefixed rule will be overridden.

This seems to work for distinguishing between the prefixed and non-prefixed files, but gives the following output:

```
~/tmp$ make
Makefile:10: warning: overriding commands for target `mpia.bin'
Makefile:7: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mpia.bin'
Makefile:10: warning: overriding commands for target `mpib.bin'
Makefile:7: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mpib.bin'
Makefile:10: warning: overriding commands for target `mpic.bin'
Makefile:7: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mpic.bin'
Makefile:10: warning: overriding commands for target `mpid.bin'
Makefile:7: warning: ignoring old commands for target `mpid.bin'
echo "bin file: " ./a.bin
bin file:  ./a.bin
echo "bin file: " ./b.bin
bin file:  ./b.bin
echo "bin file: " ./c.bin
bin file:  ./c.bin
echo "bin file: " ./d.bin
bin file:  ./d.bin
echo "mpi file: " ./mpia.bin
mpi file:  ./mpia.bin
echo "mpi file: " ./mpib.bin
mpi file:  ./mpib.bin
echo "mpi file: " ./mpic.bin
mpi file:  ./mpic.bin
echo "mpi file: " ./mpid.bin
mpi file:  ./mpid.bin
```

I'm sure that there's a way to suppress those warnings or do it better, but this approach seems to work.