# Makefile: run process and do something else after process is fully started

Tags: makefile

I've got a makefile that starts a tunslip, like this:

```
connect-router: $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6
    sudo $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6 -B $(TUNSLIP_BAUD) $(PREFIX) -v6
```

What I want is that, after this tunslip is fully initialized, it starts a daemon to populate some routing tables. What I've tried is this:

```
connect-router: $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6
    @echo "Doing tunslip"
    sudo $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6 -B $(TUNSLIP_BAUD) $(PREFIX) -v6
    @echo "Doing routing tables"
    sudo smcroute -k
    sudo smcroute -d
```

The first echo is reached, the process is started, but the other commands aren't executed, probably because the makefile is busy doing the process, never giving the second echo! However, I need the smcroute to be started after the tunnel is fully initialized so it has to be this order. How do I do this?

Edit:

```
connect-router: $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6
    @echo "Doing tunslip"
    ( sudo $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6 -B $(TUNSLIP_BAUD) $(PREFIX) -v6 )
    @echo "Doing routing tables"
    sudo smcroute -k
    sudo smcroute -d
```

Comment: As said [here][1], start your tunslip6 command in a subshell.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668311/makefile-run-processes-in-background

Comment: When run as written make just hangs at the `tunslip6` line forever?

Comment: I have put the command between () but it still doesn't work. For the exact code, see my post.

Edit: Didn't see you there! No, when run as written the tunslip6 process just executes and the other ones never get a chance to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a make question, it's a shell question.  Make is just running your commands in the shell, just as if you'd typed them at the shell prompt yourself.  If you run a command from the shell, then the shell will wait for the command to complete before continuing with the next command.

Adding parentheses won't change this, because parentheses just run the command in a sub-shell... but the parent shell still waits for the sub-shell to complete before it continues with the next command.

The only way to let one command continue while the shell runs the next command at the same time is to put the first command *in the background*, and you do this with the ampersand `&` operator:

```
connect-router: $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6
        @echo "Doing tunslip"
        sudo $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6 -B $(TUNSLIP_BAUD) $(PREFIX) -v6 &
        @echo "Doing routing tables"
        sudo smcroute -k
        sudo smcroute -d
```

Comment: I should point out that you now have a problem of how to stop that background process...

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Yes, I now indeed have that problem. I'd also still like to see the output of that background process. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/how-to-stop-a-background-process

But it doesn't appear after using jobs! So, I can't selectively or automatically bring it to the fg.

Comment: Why don't you see the output?  It should go to the terminal just like always.  You need to think carefully about _exactly_ how you want this to work, then describe it clearly, before we can help.